# How to enable vim style navigation in git bash?

Tags: git, vim, command-line, git-bash

I'm pretty tired of navigating git bash with the arrow keys and I read somewhere that you can enable vim style navigation in git bash so I was just wondering how to enable this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to simply type:

```
set -o vi
```

That will activate vi-style navigation.
I just tested it on Windows with Git 2.11.

See more at "[What is meant by a shell is in “vi” mode or “emacs” mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85395/7490)"

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why settle for a limited vi (not Vim) emulation where it doesn't make sense to begin with when you can use actual Vim?

```
<C-x><C-e>
```

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean with <C-x><C-e>?

Comment: Press Ctrl+x then Ctrl+e in your shell.

Comment: @Jason That runs vim to let you edit the command you are entering. That would allow for editing the current command using vim, but it would not allow you to navigate your history entries with `j` & `k`.

Comment: I see, sounds cool! Although it doesn't seem to work in git bash, I just receive this error: "bash: emacs: command not found"

Comment: `export EDITOR=vim`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it globally, find your bash.bashrc file , which is usually in C:\Program Files\Git\etc, and add that command mentioned at the end.

set -o vi