# How do I edit a copy pasted line in git bash?

Tags: git-bash

If I want to copy paste some code onto git bash, and edit the code somewhere in the middle, how do you do this without using arrow keys? Is it possible to edit by moving the cursor with a click?

If I want to change

```
python Sample-code.py
```

to

```
python -m Sample-code.py
```

without having to use the left arrow key

Answer (score 0):

You could [activate the `vi` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41411292/6309) (see [`vi` mode here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85396/7490))

```
set -o vi
```

Then, on your line '`python Sample-code.py`', type:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> for switching to `vi` command mode,
- <kbd>j</kbd> multiple time to get back to the -m` portion
- <kbd>x</kbd> 3 times to delete '`-m` '
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the modified line
- or <kbd>i</kbd> to switch back to 'insert' mode if you need to type more in the same line.

No left arrow needed there.